# how do you eject cd using keyboard on dell inspiron 6000

Tags: dell-inspiron, optical-drive, eject, function-keys

The eject button on my cd / dvd drive is broken. 
I can still eject using windows explorer from the context menu. 
I need to reinstall windows.
Is there a function key combination i can use from the boot up screen ?

Answer (score 5):

You can always stick a fine allen key or unfolded paper clip into the little hole (usually just under the tray):

[image]

This image is apparently of the Inspiron DVD drive and you can see the hole on the right next to the button:

[image]

Comment: I think he is talking about a laptop. I don't know if his slim dell laptop CD device has such a hole.

Comment: @Ivan - ah, I thought these were standard - indeed it appears they are. See the new screen shot

Answer (score 2):

I guess i can do:

> eject cdrom

from a ubuntu live cd.

Comment: Doesn't help him reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Eject the CD from your current install of Windows, place Windows re-install CD in drive, close, reboot, and install Windows. Windows will go through its install basic stuff, reboot, finish Windows install, and then boot up into a fresh copy of Windows. From there, you can eject the Windows CD from the new Windows.